# NoSuchMethodError while starting Hive shell

Tags: hadoop, hive

I have configured Hadoop on a single node cluster, Hadoop cluster is configured properly even I executed MapReduce in a cluster. Now I have newly installed hive tool and did configuration, but when I start Hive shell, I am getting below error.

```
[dsawale@localhost apache-hive-2.1.0-bin]$ bin/hive
which: no hbase in (/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin:/home/dsawale/hadoop-3.2.1/bin:/home/dsawale/kafka_2.11-2.4.1/bin:/home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/bin:/home/dsawale/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/bin:/home/dsawale/.local/bin:/home/dsawale/bin:/home/dsawale/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk/bin:/home/dsawale/hadoop-3.2.1/bin:/home/dsawale/kafka_2.11-2.4.1/bin:/home/dsawale/sqoop-1.4.7.bin__hadoop-2.6.0/bin:/home/dsawale/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/bin)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/dsawale/apache-hive-2.1.0-bin/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.4.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/dsawale/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.apache.logging.slf4j.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1357)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1338)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJar(JobConf.java:536)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.setJarByClass(JobConf.java:554)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.<init>(JobConf.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.initialize(HiveConf.java:3612)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf.<init>(HiveConf.java:3570)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4jCommon(LogUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.common.LogUtils.initHiveLog4j(LogUtils.java:60)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:657)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:323)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:236)
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: it seems like you dont have hbase in the hadoop core-site configuration.

Comment: @KenrySanchez Do we have to configure hbase in core-site to run hive shell?  Is it mandatory?